# Calcuate overlapping intervals of all possible pairs of rows by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to caculate the number of years over which an individual have worked with others in a group in a year (i.e., an individual's coworking experience with his/her coworkers). My data look something like below:

```
    mydata <- data.frame(group_id= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                     individual_id= c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6),
                     working_since= c(2000,2005,1998,2000,2005,2009,2005,1990),
                     current_year= c(2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009,2008,2008)
                  )
```

As can be seen, the number of indviduals belong to a group by year change over time depending on their job decisions;

Because I am interested in caculating an indidivdual's coworking experience with her colleagues in a same group up until a given year(var = current+year), there will be pariwise comparisons of all the rows within a group in a given year. The expected output would like something like the following:

```
    mydata <- data.frame(group_id= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                     individual_id= c(1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6),
                     working_since= c(2000,2005,1998,2000,2005,2009,2005,1990),
                     current_year= c(2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009,2008,2008),
                     overlapping_years_caculation= c("4+9", "4+4", "9+4", "5+1", "6+1", "1+1", "4" "4")
                     overlapping+years+result = c(13, 8, 13, 6, 7, 2, 4, 4)

                  )
```

The result assumes that the indivdual began her term at the beginning of the year.

I have been making extensive searches to see if there is any past post similar to my problem, and in fact I found it [Compare one row of a column against all others in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548487/compare-one-row-of-a-column-against-all-others-in-group#comment126455282_71548487). Unfortunately, the code provided in that post did not work on my dataset - maybe because I have separate columns for the start and end year?

Would much appreciate it if I could get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata |> 
 mutate(time_length = interval(
  dmy(paste0("0101", working_since)),
  dmy(paste0("3112", current_year)) + days(1))) |> 
 group_by(group_id, current_year) |> 
   mutate(total_overlap = map_dbl(time_length, 
                             \(x) x |> 
                               intersect(time_length) |> 
                               int_length() |> 
                               sum(na.rm = T) - int_length(x)
   ) / 86400 / 365.25
  )
```

Just pinching the code from the answer you linked and adapting it a little to your question.

That's with `library(lubridate)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different approach, `full_join`ing all individuals by group/year to get a full list of groupXyear matchings to calculate by:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- tibble(
  group_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  individual_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6),
  working_since = c(2000, 2005, 1998, 2000, 2005, 2009, 2005, 1990),
  current_year = c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2008, 2008)
)


mydata |> 
  rename(ind_2 = individual_id, work2 = working_since) |> 
  full_join(mydata, by = join_by(group_id, current_year), relationship = "many-to-many") |> 
  filter(individual_id != ind_2) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(overlap = length(intersect(working_since:current_year, work2:current_year))) |> 
  group_by(group_id, individual_id, current_year) |> 
  summarise(overlapping_years = sum(overlap), .groups = "drop") |> 
  arrange(group_id, current_year, individual_id)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 4
#>   group_id individual_id current_year overlapping_years
#>      <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>             <int>
#> 1        1             1         2008                13
#> 2        1             2         2008                 8
#> 3        1             3         2008                13
#> 4        1             1         2009                 6
#> 5        1             2         2009                 6
#> 6        1             4         2009                 2
#> 7        2             5         2008                 4
#> 8        2             6         2008                 4
```